# how to get size of array from array of arrays in c++

Tags: c++

I want help on the following code

```
    int arr_1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int arr_2[] = {6, 7, 8};
    int arr_3[] = {9, 10};

    int* arr[] = {arr_1, arr_2, arr_3, NULL};

    // print all the elements in array of arrays
    // printArray(arr);

    cout << sizeof arr_1;
    cout << sizeof *arr;
```

when I try the first cout, it gives me 20, which is correct.
but when i try the second cout, it gives me 8 which is size of a pointer variable

why. !!

could anyone give me a correct explanation and how can i get the correct size in the second way i.e from array of arrays.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have an array of arrays. You have an array of pointers. Therein lies the problem.

Comment: what do you think `int *` means?

Comment: Why? Because that's what `sizeof` does. What did you think it does?

Answer (score 2):

To count the number of elements in a static array, you can create a template function:

```
    template < typename T, size_t N >
    size_t countof( T const (&array)[ N ] )
    {
        return N;
    }
```

For standard containers such as std::vector, the size() function is used. This pattern is also used with [boost arrays](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/array.html), which are fixed size arrays and claim no worse performance to static arrays. The code you have in a comment above should be:

```
for ( std::vector::size_type i(0); i < entries.size(); ++i )
```